# Invoking CURL command from Java code throws Exception

Tags: java, curl

I am pretty new to Java and trying to fetch some values from Hashicorp vault -

When I run the curl command manually it works and returns values but when I try to run the same via code, I am running into issues.

`curl POST -H "X-Vault-Namespace: dev/rel-box-dev-seed" --data '{"param1":"3f3a-094-193a-cj2e-l6ekn516a","param2":"647a-9f3-934fd3-227e-lkrae24be37"}' https://vault.abc.com/v1/auth/role/login`

My Java code is as follows -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaRunCommand {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = null;
        try {
            List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
            commands.add("curl");
            commands.add("POST");
            commands.add("-H");
            commands.add("\\\"X-Vault-Namespace: dev/rel-box-dev-seed\\\"");
            commands.add("--data");
            commands.add("'{\"param1\":\"3f3a-094-193a-cj2e-l6ekn516a\",\"param2\":\"647a-9f3-934fd3-227e-lkrae24be37\"}'");
            commands.add("https://vault.abc.com/v1/auth/role/login");

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
            Process p = pb.start();


            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception happened - here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following error - 
`curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or if there is a better way to do curl operation?

Comment: `curl POST` is most likely wrong already to begin with. That `POST` word should be removed.

Comment: I did try removing the word `POST` and saw the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the quotes around the arguments?  A ProcessBuilder will quote the arguments for you, so you don't need to quote them again:

```
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
        commands.add("curl");
        commands.add("POST");
        commands.add("-H");
        commands.add("X-Vault-Namespace: dev/rel-box-dev-seed");
        commands.add("--data");
        commands.add("{\"param1\":\"3f3a-094-193a-cj2e-l6ekn516a\",\"param2\":\"647a-9f3-934fd3-227e-lkrae24be37\"}");
        commands.add("https://vault.app.ford.com/v1/auth/approle/login");
```

Comment: It doesn't accept the values if I remove quotes. It expects a String value.

I have also tried calling the curl command directly by declaring the curl as a String value and passing it to the Process as -  
 String value = "<curl command>";
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(value); and it didn't work.

Comment: @Cerebro: it's not clear what you mean by "expects a String value".  All the values above are strings: have you removed more quotes than what I did in my answer?  (I only removed the excessive quotes (and backslashes) on the `X-Vault-Namespace` line, and the single quotes at the beginning and end of the parameter with JSON in it.

Comment: Also, your comment about passing the whole command as one string is unhelpful in two ways: firstly, you don't specify the exact command line you are running (please edit your question to include this string), and secondly, you write "it didn't work".  I have no idea whether you got the same error or any one of potentially thousands of others, so it's impossible to offer any help that way.

Comment: Apologies for not explaining correctly. I did try and remove the extra quotes and backslashes from X-Vault-Namespace and got the following error 
`{"errors":["failed to parse JSON input: invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"]}`.

Comment: When I passed the entire curl command `String value = "curl POST -H \"X-Vault-Namespace: dev/rel-box-dev-seed\" --data '{\"param1\":\"3f3a-094-193a-cj2e-l6ekn516a\",\"param2\":\"647a-9f3-934fd3-227e-lkrae24be37\"}' https://vault.abc.com/v1/auth/role/login";
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(value);`


I got the following error - 

`{"errors":["failed to parse JSON input: invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"]}`

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation here is to watch this traffic across the wire with something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), Wireshark, or tcpdump. Then, compare these two requests. There is some difference in how you are preparing them (maybe with quotes, as Luke Woodward suggested, or maybe some other difference.) Inspecting the two requests, and comparing them for differences, will help you understand your problem in this instance as well as help you improve request comparison in the future, in general.